# How can I control an AC reversible motor using a single switch?

Tags: motor, ac

I am an software engineer and not very experienced regarding electronics.

Basically I want to "control" an AC reversible motor (50TYD) using a single switch (S3).

- When S3 is ON phase L1 on the motor input should be active and L2 should be inactive
- When S3 is OFF L2 should be active and L1 inactive.

Is there any way to do this without adding any other components?
S1 and S2 is ON default when not pressed by the motor.

I have done my best to draw a diagram:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Please consider using an appropriately (voltage and current) rated changeover electromechanical relay. The coil for the relay must also be chosen to match the voltage from switch S3.

You should also implement a method (interlock) that prevents reversal when the motor is already spinning. This can be achieved with a centrifugal switch.

Comment: Hi Andy. Thank you for your comment. As far as i can seen the motor has a rated voltage of 220-240VAC and rated power of 6W. Can you help me find the right relay component to add to the circuit?

Comment: I can look at a relay that you specify and see if it's any good for the job. I can't find a relay on your behalf because that requires me to know the availability of devices in your area of the world.

Comment: I found this one: https://res.cloudinary.com/evoleska/image/upload/v1607348816/wcnd4ehcpdjrccpo3mjv.pdf
More specifically the 2CO 10A 230VAC variant. Will this work?

Comment: What supply voltage is used by the motor? What is the current taken at initial start-up? What is the motor full-load current? It looks a decent part btw @anton-definit <-- another thought, you would probably need to implement a method of detecting that the motor has stopped before allowing it to be reversed. This can be done using a centrifugal switch.